# Editing a web application developed with yii

Tags: yii2

I know it might sound dumb, but I'm new to this framework. A client has an application that was developed with yii, now he needs some few changes made, like some spellings, changing the content of the copyright on the footer. I tried editing using Dreamweaver, but I don't seem to locate any of the texts. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: use  a  text editor like notepad++ ore sublimetext or notepad. is only php code..and html

Comment: @scaisEdge i tried that, but no result. you know, like a normal website, you see the pages and work on em. bu this one you don't see the specific pages. for example I want to change the copyright info on the footer. I don't see any footer file!

Comment: i have post an answer. I hope this could be usefu

Comment: I suggest you search all files for the string that you need to change and change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a text editor like notepad++ ore sublimetext or notepad. is only php code..and html

for the footer look at source code of the application. If the version is Yii 1* you can find this part of code in layout. If you use the default theme you find the layout in `yourApp/protected/view/layouts/`
 if the application use a specific theme the layout are in  `yourApp/theme/yourThemename/layouts/`

look for the file you need (normally main.php)

If the framework version is 2.* the layout are in `yourApp/view/layouts`

Comment: thanks very much @scaisEdge, it worked for me. the path is yourApp/view/layouts/. i found all the files I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks you too. if my answer is useful as well as accepted mark also indicates how useful using the up arrow